# How to know if a link is active in a view script without using Zend\Mvc\Navigation ? ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm using Zend Framework 2.
I'd like test if a link is the active page in my view script.

For example :

on my view script : view/application/account/user.phtml

```
<a href="$this->url("account")" 
<?echo **if($this->isActive()**){?> class="active"<?php } ?>link</a>
```

I don't want to set menu with Zend\Mvc\Navigation

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this:

```
<?php $current_url = $this->url(); ?>

<a href="<?php echo $this->url('account'); ?>" <?php if ($current_url == $this->url('account')) { echo 'class="active"'; } ?>>link</a>
```

Comment: $current_url = $this->url(); give me the route path, but without controler, et action params :s

Comment: $this->url() give me the route path like /account/ but without controller and action params, like /account/user/1. I want the last.